# Confirming that phone number data is formatted correctly

Tags: sqlite

I need to check the data in a column of phone numbers to ensure it's formatted as:

(XXX) XXX-XXXX

I already know that there are rows with incorrectly formatted entries such as:
(123)456-7890
1234567890; 5678901223

I've tried a number of queries, but this felt the closest, yet still returned no values:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE telephone_number like '([000-9]) ([000-999])-([0000-9999])';
```

Thank you in advance for any help,
Christie

Comment: that like only matches the literal value provided (it has no wildcards (`%`, `_`)), so all phone numbers should be returned with that sql statement. if you aren't getting any values, then that can't be the code you are running

Comment: @jhnc oops, you are right, I mistyped; I ran 'like' and got no values. I've edited my code above.

Comment: sqlite doesn't have regexes by default. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators) operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE telephone_number GLOB '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

which returns the correct formatted values, or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE telephone_number NOT GLOB '([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

which returns the incorrect formatted values.

Or, with shorter code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE telephone_number GLOB REPLACE('(XXX) XXX-XXXX', 'X', '[0-9]');
```

and:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE telephone_number NOT GLOB REPLACE('(XXX) XXX-XXXX', 'X', '[0-9]');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ynQRxvzb).